# Keep grid intact when adding breaks in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2

I want to highlight a specific value on my x-axis. However when I add these values, the gridlines in my plot are a bit messed up. See between 2002 and 2004. How do I fix this?

[image]

My code:

```
test_set <- structure(list(year = c(2000, 2005, 2010), index = c(7.24189432608059, 
7.29732635140488, 5.57837924621813)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


test_set |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = index)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2001, linetype=3) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2006, linetype=2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2007, linetype=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2001, 2007, seq(2000, 2010, 2))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me (but I might be wrong as a similar issue was already reported on [GH](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4440)). But one option to fix your issue would be to explicitly set the `minor_breaks=`, e.g. using `scales::breaks_width(1)` to get a minor break for each year:

```r
library(ggplot2)

test_set |>
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = index)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2001, linetype = 3) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2006, linetype = 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2007, linetype = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(2001, 2007, seq(2000, 2010, 2)),
    minor_breaks = scales::breaks_width(1)
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I've fixed the plot for you by removing the minor grid.

```
test_set |> 
        ggplot(aes(x = year, y = index)) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_vline(xintercept = 2001, linetype=3) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = 2006, linetype=2) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = 2007, linetype=1) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2001, 2007, seq(2000, 2010, 2))) +
        theme_minimal()+
        theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]